# How to fix 'TypeError: not enough arguments for format string' error in Python

Tags: python

Sorry for the extremely basic question; I'm new to Python. This is a question on pythonprinciples.com that wants me to define a function called outer and it must contain two inner lists which can contain anything.

Exact question for reference, "Write a function named nested_lists that defines a list named outer and returns it. The outer list must contain two inner lists, which can contain anything you want."

Sorry for any formatting problems; it's my first post here.

```
def nested_lists(outer):
    outer[0] = [1, 2]
    outer[1] = [3, 4]
    return outer
```

I tried my code out in IDLE and got this.

```
nested_lists([1, 2, 3 ,4, 5])
[[1, 2], [3, 4], 3, 4, 5]
```

These are my expected results but on the, website it gives me the TypeError.

Comment: Well, your output does not just contain a list with two inner lists. It is a list with two inner lists and then three integers.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to say to receive a list as a parameter? Just to define and return it.

Comment: Your program, with this call, substitutes the two first elements with two lists. So it returns a list that contains two lists and three more elements... Moreover, as previous coment says, it needs a list with two elements at least as an input, which is different from the statement of the problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As a new user, you really, really should read [ask]. There are good advices there that you should follow. Here, Python is highly sensitive to indentation so you should pay attention to code formatting. And anyway, the TypeError you quote in your title cannot be raised from the code you show (which is correct BTW). Because of that, this question is *unclear* and could be closed. The key is to provide a true [mcve] exhibiting the problem.

Comment: Please also provide sample expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what they're looking for is something like this:

```
def nested_lists():
    outer = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
    return outer
```

your function works fine, but their website is not handling it particularly well. I don't think that site looks like a good place to learn python (not that it's bad, just perhaps there are better options) - there is a list on this page https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info of good tutorials that might be worth looking at.

Comment: Your answer is right. Looks like I wasn't following the instructions clearly enough. Outer wasn't the parameter, it's a variable.  That's what I got confused with. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
def nested_lists(outer):
    outer.append([1],[2])
    return outer
```

I checked the site and did some of their practice questions, the TypeError you mentioned pops up on every failed test case. I think they are looking for something like the solution above.

Comment: It can't be this solution, for the website has not even started to cover appends yet( I also don't know what it does). Your answer also comes up with the same error. I got the answer though in the other reply and outer isn't the parameter, it's a variable that I was meant to make. Thanks for the help, though.